# Free New Line condition check in C Linux

Tags: c

currently I am using
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

```
if(dup != NULL || dup[0] != '\0') {
    free(dup);                               
}
```

I am having problem here, that where ever dup contains `'\n'`, it will try to free it and give me segmentation fault. i don't want to put a hard coded `'\n'` condition check for dup, I just want to free the dup variable if it is not `NULL`, but if it contain `'\n'` then it is failing and giving me segmentation faults.

Comment: What type is `dup`? You can't free a single `char`; `dup` has to be a pointer (`'\n'` is not a pointer). Show more relevant code.

Comment: Do you like `SEGFAULT`s? If `dup == NULL` you dereference `dup[0]`. Bad idea.

Comment: Also, I suspect you're doing something rather dangerous. An empty string is preferable to a wild pointer, and neither are the same thing as a `NULL`-pointer. Don't free a string just because it's empty. Free it because you are sure it's not going to be used anywhere ever again.

Comment: You only want to use `free` when the pointer points to heap memory.  Also, you need to change the `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect here:

```
if(dup != NULL || dup[0] != '\0') {
```

should be:

```
if(dup != NULL && dup[0] != '\0') {
```

otherwise you will attempt to de-reference NULL pointers.